# AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json') Error

Tags: config.json

I'm on step 3 of this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-lambda-functions.html

When run `AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json')`
I got bash: `syntax error near unexpected token` './config.json''`

I tried changing the directory to include the full path but no luck. Have 3 people checking my config.json file and confirmed that looks fine too.

Comment: You're getting an error from bash, but `AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json')` is definitely not bash code.

Comment: Good point! Do you happen to know if there is any workaround for this? I still couldn't figure out the reason of the error...

Comment: I have no idea because I can't see any of the code you're running.